# Embedding local plotly graph into local html page

Tags: javascript, html, r, plotly, google-earth

I generated an interactive graph using Plotly library in R and another one using radarchart package , then insert both of them into local html page which in Google Earth Pro program, the radarchart showed into the properties page but the plotly graph didn't show... i don't know why, so any help please ? i spent alot of hours looking for solution but couldn't find any .

here's my data for plotly graph "DailyData"

```
structure(list(Day = c("Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Sunday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday"
), Type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Accidents", 
"Fatalities", "Injuries"), class = "factor"), No. = c(66, 6, 
73, 61, 26, 117, 54, 6, 70, 57, 21, 47, 53, 10, 48, 69, 23, 80, 
52, 5, 38)), .Names = c("Day", "Type", "No."), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21"), class = "data.frame")
```

**and here's the code**

```
  R2 <- ggplot()+geom_bar(data=DailyData,aes(x=reorder(Day,as.single(row.names(DailyData))),y=No.,group = as.factor(Type),fill=Type),stat = "identity",position = "dodge")+
            labs(x="Day")
    R2 <- ggplotly(R2,tooltip = c("No.","Type"))
    R2name <- paste0(name,"Daily.html")
    saveWidget(R2,R2name)
```

Here're photos showing what i mean

photo showing the radarchart in local html page of google earth pro
[image]

photo showing that **plotly chart** doesn't appear into html page 
[image]

here's a photo showing the **HTML code** i use for both of them .
[image]

here's the code

```
<iframe src="file:Graphs/Cairo_Assiut(WestRd)Radar.html" width="960" height="500" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"></iframe>

<iframe src="file:Graphs/Cairo_Assiut(WestRd)Daily.html" width="960" height="500" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
```

Is there a mistake into my html code of plotly chart ? which is the second code ? please help

Comment: Can you add the HTML code as txt and not as a screenshot?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters done